# How to remove local storage data after uninstallation of the teams custom tab app from teams store

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-teams-js

I made an **teams custom tab application** which stores data in local storage But it stores the data even after uninstalling the application. So is there any way to remove that local storage data after uninstalling the application from the Teams app store.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to clear the local storage data for your Teams app (a custom tab). To achieve that, you can open the DevTools and then use "Clear Site Data" command there (similar to the normal browser, the biggest button on the "Application" tab). To access the DevTools, you click the "Open DevTools" context menu.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/developer-tools

Comment: My understanding is that I am familiar with accessing developer tools in Microsoft Teams and that is not the current concern. My concern is how to clear the user token from local storage before a custom tab is uninstalled. The reason for this is that when I uninstall the app and then reinstall it, the session remains in local storage, allowing the user to go to the home page without going through the login screen. Can you please tell me if there is a way to achieve this

Comment: Sorry for confusion. If you have a login screen, doesn't this means you log in the user somehow and store the authentication yourself? I.e. if your application knows where it stores the authentication data, then on uninstall you can just delete it from that place? If I still do not understand, maybe you could elaborate the description so that its easier to get. If you are using some framework to authenticate users, please specify, maybe it could be helpful.

Comment: Meaning, by default, as far as I know, teams client itself does not store any authentication data for a tab. It's probably your tab application itself that stores it? If you are using MSAL library or something like this, you could check the documentation of that library how to clear its saved data, and do that when the user removes the app.

Comment: The problem at hand is that when the logout button is clicked, the user is successfully logged out and directed back to the login screen. However, if the Teams tab extension is uninstalled, the user's access token remains saved in the local storage. As the uninstallation of the Teams tab is not within our control and is carried out by MS Teams, is there a method to ensure that the user is logged out before or after the uninstallation of the Teams tab, such as through a Teams REST API or callback function to clear the local storage?

Comment: The login/logout buttons are presumably part of your application, right? Also, uninstall experience for your application is part of your application, you define the page to load for uninstall in your teams application configuration.

Comment: Check out the "remove" part in teams docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/create-tab-pages/removal-page?tabs=teamsjs-v2